# Why is FormulaR1C1 putting unwanted brackets into formula?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making a template which will include a formula in every cell of column `C`, which my colleague can just copy into his working sheets. For that I put a variable row number to work properly in my colleague's working environment.

```vb
For i = 2 To x
    Sheets("Worksheet").Range("C" & i).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=INDEX('S2.0 - Setup'!B:I,MATCH(INDIRECT(""C"" & ROW()),'S2.0 - Setup'!I:I,0),1)"
Next
```

I expect to be in `C2`:

```
=INDEX('S2.0 - Setup'!B:I);MATCH(INDIRECT("C" & ROW());'S2.0 - Setup'!I:I;0);1)
```

But the result is:

```
=INDEX('S2.0 - Setup'!B:(I);MATCH(INDIRECT("C" & ROW());'S2.0 - Setup'!I:(I);0);1)
```

So Excel is putting those brackets in the ranges `B:I` and `I:I`.

Comment: Why are you trying to use both A1 and R1C1 styles in a single formula? For column `C`, `B:I` should be `C[-1]:C[6]`, and `I:I` should be `C[6]`. You most likely meant `$B:$I` and `$I:$I` though, that would be `C2:C9` and `C9` regardless of the target cell.

Comment: You should be using `.Formula` not `.FormulaR1C1`.

Comment: Actually, looking at the formula, you don't appear to need R1C1 to begin with. Assign to `.Formula`, not to `.FormulaR1C1`.

Comment: Thank you for you replies. I just mix up `.Formula` and `.FormulaR1C1`. Now it works flawless.

Answer (score -2):

### VBA to Excel Formula

### The Code

```
Sub VBAtoExcelFormula()

    Const cVntSource As String = "S2.0 - Setup"   ' Source Worksheet Name/Index
    Const cVntTarget As String = "Worksheet"      ' Target Worksheet Name/Index
    Const cStrFirstColumn As String = "B"  ' Source First Column Letter
    Const cStrLRColumn As String = "I"     ' Source Last Row Column Letter
    Const cStrFormula As String = "C"      ' Target Formula Column Letter

    Dim i As Long             ' Row Counter
    Dim lngLastRow As Long    ' Source/Target Last Row
    Dim strFormula As String  ' Formula String

    With Sheets(cVntSource)
        lngLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, cStrLRColumn).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    For i = 2 To lngLastRow
        strFormula = "=INDEX('" & cVntSource & "'!" & cStrFirstColumn _
                & ":" & cStrLRColumn & ",MATCH(INDIRECT(""" & cStrFormula _
                & """&ROW()),'" & cVntSource & "'!" & cStrLRColumn _
                & ":" & cStrLRColumn & ",0),1)"
        Debug.Print strFormula
        Sheets(cVntTarget).Cells(i, cStrFormula).Formula = strFormula
    Next

End Sub

Sub VBAtoExcelFormulaShort()

    Const cVntLRColumn As Variant = "I"  ' Source Last Row Column Letter/Number

    Dim i As Long             ' Row Counter
    Dim lngLastRow As Long    ' Source/Target Last Row
    Dim strFormula As String  ' Formula String

    With Sheets("S2.0 - Setup")
        lngLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, cVntLRColumn).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    For i = 2 To lngLastRow
        strFormula = "=INDEX('S2.0 - Setup'!B:I,MATCH(INDIRECT(""C""&ROW()),'" _
                & "S2.0 - Setup'!I:I,0),1)"
        Debug.Print strFormula
        Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(i, "C").Formula = strFormula
    Next

End Sub
```